# Host Menu Items are not visible in DotNetNUke

Tags: dotnetnuke-5

I am using DNN 5.2.2, host menu items are not visible on site when i click on host menu it return me blank page http://...../host.aspx
Can any let me know what is the problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer.(Dnn 5.6)
The following SQL scripts were run:

- `UPDATE Tabs SET PortalID = Null
  where TabPath Like '//Host%' AND
  PortalID Is Not Null`
- `UPDATE Tabs SET ParentId = Null
  where TabID=7`